# fail2ban doesn't find attacker anymore

Tags: fail2ban

The IP 218.92.1.158 is currently attacking my Raspberry.

Until this morning, `fail2ban` was blocking it correctly.
`/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` :

```
[DEFAULT]
bantime = 3600
findtime = 3600
maxretry = 5
```

The only thing I did since then, is adding a cron job that copies the `/var/log/auth.log` file and empties it:

```
0   0  *   *   *     bash -c "cp /var/log/auth.log ~/auths/auth$((`ls ~/auths/auth* | sed -n 's/\/root\/auths\/auth\([0-9]*\)/\1/p' | sort -rh | head -n 1`+1))" && echo "" > /var/log/auth.log
```

This works. Just in case it could have changed the permissions, here they are currently:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 52569 Dec 22 15:20 /var/log/auth.log
```

Since then, the attacker doesn't get banned anymore. Here is an extract of `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
# cat /var/log/auth.log | grep "Failed" | grep 218.92.1.158
Dec 22 15:22:55 JMPi sshd[29568]: Failed password for root from 218.92.1.158 port 18727 ssh2
Dec 22 15:23:54 JMPi sshd[29577]: Failed password for root from 218.92.1.158 port 18945 ssh2
Dec 22 15:23:57 JMPi sshd[29577]: Failed password for root from 218.92.1.158 port 18945 ssh2
Dec 22 15:23:59 JMPi sshd[29577]: Failed password for root from 218.92.1.158 port 18945 ssh2
Dec 22 15:24:58 JMPi sshd[29588]: Failed password for root from 218.92.1.158 port 13087 ssh2
Dec 22 15:25:01 JMPi sshd[29588]: Failed password for root from 218.92.1.158 port 13087 ssh2
Dec 22 15:25:04 JMPi sshd[29588]: Failed password for root from 218.92.1.158 port 13087 ssh2
```

This makes 6 tries in the 1-hour time frame.

Looking at `/var/log/fail2ban.log`:

```
# cat /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep "218.92.1.158"
2018-12-22 13:38:09,068 fail2ban.filter         [29522]: INFO    [sshd] Found 218.92.1.158
2018-12-22 13:38:09,726 fail2ban.actions        [29522]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 218.92.1.158
2018-12-22 13:38:10,730 fail2ban.filter         [29522]: INFO    [sshd] Found 218.92.1.158
2018-12-22 14:38:09,853 fail2ban.actions        [29522]: NOTICE  [sshd] Unban 218.92.1.158
```

It's been an hour that `fail2ban` doesn't find the attacker anymore, despite him continuously trying.

I've restarted `fail2ban` multiple times:

```
# service fail2ban status
● fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-12-22 15:32:07 CET; 4s ago
     Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
  Process: 30011 ExecStop=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 30094 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client -x start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 30098 (fail2ban-server)
   CGroup: /system.slice/fail2ban.service
           └─30098 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/fail2ban-server -s /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock -p /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid -x -b

Dec 22 15:32:03 JMPi systemd[1]: Starting Fail2Ban Service...
Dec 22 15:32:04 JMPi fail2ban-client[30094]: ERROR  No file(s) found for glob /var/log/nginx/*access.log
Dec 22 15:32:04 JMPi fail2ban-client[30094]: ERROR  No file(s) found for glob /var/log/lighttpd/error.log
Dec 22 15:32:04 JMPi fail2ban-client[30094]: 2018-12-22 15:32:04,610 fail2ban.server         [30096]: INFO    Starting Fail2ban v0.9.6
Dec 22 15:32:04 JMPi fail2ban-client[30094]: 2018-12-22 15:32:04,611 fail2ban.server         [30096]: INFO    Starting in daemon mode
Dec 22 15:32:07 JMPi systemd[1]: Started Fail2Ban Service.
```

Despite the two file errors (which are not used by my installation anyway), `fail2ban` does seem to be running.

Unlike [Why is fail2ban finding but not banning](https://serverfault.com/questions/825811/why-is-fail2ban-finding-but-not-banning), the tries definitely are in the time window.

Do you have any idea what could cause that ?

Comment: What does `sudo fail2ban-client status sshd` say?

Comment: You should use `logrotate` to rotate your system logs, not manual entries in crontab.

Comment: I changed it to use `logrotate` and now there's no problems anymore... I'm unsure what I did.